# PC Lagging After Installing New M.2 SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, performance

My Pc:

- 3 Monitors
- Windows 10 pro
- Ryzen R7 1700
- GTX 1060 3GB
- ASRock AB350 Pro4
- Crucial P1 1tb 3D NaND NVMe PCIe M.2 SSD - CT1000P1SSD8

So After I installed my new SSD and letting my computer run for a while my games would get this sort of latency like lag. Restarting my computer would fix this sort of stuttering so I thought it might be the drive getting too hot for some reason. However, I checked the temps while I was playing and they were around 50C. I had also overclocked my CPU to 3.5Ghz, but then brought that back to base-clock and the issue is still persisting. I'm just trying to figure out why this sort of stuff is happening and how I can fix it. It only happens when I leave my computer on for a bit.

Comment: You reinstalled a fresh copy of windows on the new drive? OR this M.2 SSD is a back up drive?

Comment: It was a fresh install. This drive is now the only drive I have in my system

Comment: Maybe it's possible the SSD is bad? Are you 100% sure it was brand new? what kind of drive were you using before this current one?

Comment: What happens when you reduce to only 1 monitor?

Comment: The drive was brand new from amazon and before I was using a Silicon power 120GB ssd + 1TB HDD. I have also tried switching to just 1 monitor.

Comment: If you still have the old drive, and it still has windows installed. Try seeing if your computer goes back to running like normal again.